# ckanext-harvest: error when "configuration" is set in harvest source

Tags: ckan

I am having difficulty with the CKAN harvester extension.

If I leave the "Configuration" empty, harvest works, but if I put some values in there, I get `'dict' object has no attribute 'append'` error for each dataset.

I followed the example listed in the [extension page](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest). 
Examples of configuration object I tried:

```
{ 
"default_tags":["Brisbane"], 
"default_extras":{"Source":"{harvest_source_url}"}, 
"override_extras":true 
}
```

or

```
{ "default_tags":["Brisbane"] }
```

or

```
{ "default_extras":{"State/Territory":"QLD"} }
```

etc.

How can I add tags and extras when importing?
What is the correct format for the configuration object?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your tags line to be a list of dicts:

```
"default_tags":[{"name": "Brisbane"}],
```

It sounds like you've hit a bug with the default_extras, and you'd be best to raise an [issue](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/issues) and provide full details of the harvest source, stacktrace and ckanext-harvest version. UPDATE: this issue has now been [resolved].(https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/issues/249)

Comment: Sorry for leaving this for ages.. but when I updated CKAN version it worked a bit, and I could set set tags. Been trying different things with configuration but no luck with extra field and organization.

Comment: Before I file the issue ticket, can I ask - do I use what is visible on screen as key of 'default extras'? (eg. State/Territory? or should it be state_territory like I can see as 'key' field of 'package_extra' table of PostgreSQL?) Also, what do I use as value for 'default organization'? - id/name/title from database?

Comment: The key is like what's in postgres table, or when you view the dataset via the API (package_show) i.e. "state_territory". The value for "default_group" (which also works for organizations) is the org name or id (from database or API or URL).

Comment: Thanks .. just realized tags didn't work either. Submitted the issue as you suggested.

Comment: For everyone's benefit reading this, here's the issue: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/issues/249 and you'll see work done to improve things.

Answer (score 0):

There is still the error `'dict' object has no attribute 'append'` in setting `default_extras` when the remote dataset has no extras at all.

The ticket https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/issues/289 has a pull request associated that fixes that problem.